# To make "/dev/dsp1" exist, which configs should I enable?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, config, kernel-module, alsa

My program needs to open "/dev/dsp1". But my compiled kernel does not have this file. To have this file, which configs in .config should I enable?
Thanks

Comment: Device files are usually only created when the hardware and driver both exist. The driver for your hardware may be built as a loadable module.  lspci may have a line for your hardware.

Answer (score 0):

`CONFIG_SND_OSSEMUL` (Enable OSS Emulation) and `CONFIG_SND_PCM_OSS` (OSS PCM (digital audio) API).

Also read the [Notes on Kernel OSS-Emulation](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/v4.10/sound/designs/oss-emulation.html).

Comment: Besides, do you know which part of code determines that whether "/dev/dsp1/ is added or not?

Comment: I enable these two configs and compile. But "dev/dsp1" still does not exist

Comment: Did you read the documentation? Which of the devices listed by `aplay -l` do you want to access?`